# Audio recorder application doesn't record

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, media

I've this code that work in genymotion enviroment. I need to record audio, so this is my code:

controllers.js

```
    .controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaMedia, $ionicPlatform) {


            function __log(e, data) {
              log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
            }
            var recorder = null;


            $scope.onSuccess = function() {
              console.log('Media success');
            }
            $scope.onError = function(e) {
              console.log('Media error', e);
            } 
            $scope.onStatus = function(type) {
              console.log('Media status', type);
            }

            $scope.startRecording = function () {
              if (recorder == null) {
                  console.log('init recorder');
                  recorder = new Media('record.mp3', $scope.onSuccess, $scope.onError, $scope.onStatus);
              }
              recorder.startRecord();
              recordBtn.disabled = true;
              stopBtn.disabled = false;
              __log('startRecording');
            }
            $scope.stopRecording = function() {
              recorder.stopRecord();
              __log('stopRecording');
            }
            $scope.playRecording = function() {
              recorder.play();
              __log('playRecording');
              __log( JSON.stringify(recorder) )
              console.log( JSON.stringify(recorder) );
            }
```

record.html

```
      <button id='recordBtn' ng-click='startRecording()'>record</button>
      <button id='stopBtn'  ng-click='stopRecording()'>stop</button>
      <button id='playBtn' ng-click='playRecording()'>play</button>

  <h2>Log</h2>
  <pre id="log"></pre>
```

My problem is when i run my app in ionic viewer, and i click to #recordBtn, , nothing happens, startRecording() not work. Thank you !

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: i found the solution ! Ionic not emulate to media plugin :( I published my apk, i installed it and work !